# R circular "linked" list: adding +1 to last index brings you to first index

Tags: r, list, vector

I'm trying to implement  movement through four points, while recording which points I visit. Think of it as a square. I can move from corner to corner or diagonally.

If you 'unwrap' the square you get a straight line with four points, which can be thought of as `1-2-3-4-` where after 4 it goes back to 1. So if I'm at point 2 I can move to 1 and 3 directly or 4 diagonally. I'd implement that as `2-1 / 2+1` for corner-to-corner or `2+/-2` for diagonally. The problem occurs when I'm at 2 and will try to subtract 2 where I'll end up outside of the list.

The thought I've had is that if I could somehow translate my "out of bounds" numbers to in bounds this would be solved. One solution is hard coding that:

```
 0=4 
-1=3 
 5=1 
 6=2
```

but I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this, however I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I have no idea about that R thinkg but according to Bing https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_operators.htm has regular operators to implement circular buffer with modulo division as you've already found for all other languages... Any reason that did not work for you?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov such a simple solution. I hadn't used this before. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me all you want is modular arithmetic (bless the lord for math)

```
magicFun <- function (x) x %% 4
```

Here is a simple test run

```
> magicFun(0:6)
[1] 0 1 2 3 0 1 2
```

---

**Addendum**

It's more about math but the reason it works for negatives is that in `Z/nZ` ("the world where `n` is equal to `0`") `n` is "identified" to `0`.

- This means you can add `n` as many times as you wish to a given number without changing it's "value".
- Also, by convention the numbers in `Z/nZ` are listed as `{0, 1, ..., n-1}`.

So suppose `n = 4` and `x = -6`, by the above `x = x + 2*4 = 2`.

Comment: bless the lord indeed. I hadn't used mod on a negative number before, never occured to me... Still not sure how that works, gotta read up on it. The solution however does work.

Comment: @George I've added a few notes about modular arithmetic maybe that'll help :)

Comment: tbh the mathematical formula  a-floor(a/b)*b makes perfect sense to me. Found an explanation last night which I can't seem to find again.